# App crashes when stepping through assembly code

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I have a simple cocoa test app.

I want to do this: Replace @NSApplicationMain with a swift main file. Call function NSApplicationMain from the swift file. Place a break-point on the function and step through the assembly of the app's bootstrapping process.

But as I step into instruction eventually the app crashes as shown in the screenshot. If I run the app without stepping through the assembly the app starts just fine.

Could anyone point me in the direction of what could be the problem? I'm on Xcode 8 Beta 2.

[image]

Comment: Try looking in your device console.  dyld may be printing an error there.  It looks like you're trying to call an external function that dyld cannot resolve. I don't believe this has anything to do with stepping through assembly in xcode, that's not what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for responding. If I don't do any manual stepping through code everything works fine. If I do certain combinations of step over etc everything works. The error just manifests itself when stepping through code line by line. Strange!